# SQL Server Field with 8000 characters -- text or nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am adding a field to a SQL Server 2008 database.  The field needs to accomodate up to 8000 characters (occasionally Unicode chars as well).  Seems from my research that text data type is being deprecated.  Go with nvarchar or stick with text anyway for such a large field?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation on new design is never to use features that are being deprecated without a good reason.  If it's possible that this application will survive to see a newer version of SQL Server then I wouldn't do it.  I'd use NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: you mean nvarchar(4000) or varchar(8000) ?

Comment: @gbn: Oh geez, yes.  Thanks!  I meant (max).  Edited to change.

Answer (score 1):

For up to 8000 with unicode, you can **only** use nvarchar(max)

The limit for nvarchar is 4000 without using a LOB data types (max, that is)

"text" is deprecated (and frankly rubbish compared to max types)

Answer (score 0):

There is always `nvarchar(max)` which is the replacement for `ntext`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx

(Also supported in SQL Sever 2005.)